# Code not creating directories

Tags: c#, system.io.directory

I'm trying to write a folder to the desktop. So far, I've gotten to this point. I initialize the method like this:

```
 public class Initialize 
        {
            public static void Main () 
            {
                Folder.CreateFolder();
            }
        }
```

And it takes the code from here:

```
public class Folder
    {
        public static void CreateFolder()
        {
            string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop); //Gets desktop folder
            if(System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path); 
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm thinking part of my problem is in the CreateDirectory call, but I'm not sure. All I know is only a terminal pops up, and no folder is created. Can anyone see the error? Let me know, thanks in advance!

Comment: BTW Doesn't the desktop folder always exist anyway?

Comment: This code won't create a directory anyway, as when it's fixed as indicated by @Ashkan, it'll try to create the Desktop directory, which already exists...

Comment: Why is it saying "If directory exists, create it"?

Comment: If you wish to create a directory on your desktop, then just combine the Desktop directory with your intended directory name (using Path.Combine method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). But you should only create that directory if it doesn't already exist, rather than if it does. And don't try to create the Desktop directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must Try to create folder if it does not exist and also use
`Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory`
instead of
`Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop`

Add `!` to your comparison

```
public class Folder
    {
        public static void CreateFolder()
        {
            string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory); //Gets desktop folder
            if(!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could just call Directory.CreateDirectory, because this code will internally check if the directory is existing or not.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Enviorment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory` instead, the `Enviorment.SpecialFolder.Desktop` enumeration is a virtual folder.